# magento2 Element 'referenceContainer': The attribute 'name' is required but missing

Tags: php, magento2

```
  <referenceBlock name="breadcrumbs" remove="true" />
    <referenceContainer name="page.top">
        <block class="Burstonline\EverCrumbs\Block\Evercrumbs" name="crumbs" as="crumbs" template="Magento_Catalog::breadcrumbs.phtml" />
    </referenceContainer>
```

magento 2 breadcrumbs show error
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\ValidationException): Element 'referenceContainer': The attribute 'name' is required but missing.
Line: 1557

Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\ValidationException): Element 'referenceContainer': The attribute 'name' is required but missing.
Line: 1557

Answer (score 1):

Hi @aaron seems like you tried to remove breadcrumbs and add your custom breadcrumbs, in order to solve this issue, You have to change referenceBlock to and referenceContainer.

```
<referenceContainer name="breadcrumbs" remove="true" />
```

this will fix your error.